# How to retrieve meridiem indicator from a datetime object?

Tags: datetime

Given a `datetime` object:

```
a_date = datetime.strptime('17-11-2013 2:30 AM', "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p")
```

How to retrieve the meridiem indicator('AM') ?

One solution could be:

```
a_date.strftime("%p") or a_date.time().strftime("%p")
```

Output:

```
'AM'
```

Other methods to get the same output? Thanks.

Comment: tag as python ? might get right audience

Comment: Sounds like you already have a solution.  Unless you have a problem with this output, and describe that problem, then it is off topic here.  If you are just looking for a better or different way of doing something that works, then you could ask for a code review at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Has anyone an answer ?